# Simple PHP routing

Tags: php, url-routing

I am setting up a simple routing system for my new custom MVC framework that I am making.

Currently my router class views the URL as such:

```
www.example.com/controller/controller_action/some/other/params
```

So, essentially...I've been reserving the first two segments of the URI for controller routing. However, what if I just want to run the following?

```
www.example.com/controller/some/other/params
```

...which would attempt to just run the default controller action and send the extra parameters to it?

Here is the simple router I'm using:

```
    \* --- htaccess --- *\
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]

    \* --- index.php --- *\
    if (array_key_exists('rt',$_GET)) {
        $path = $_GET['rt'];
        $uri = explode('/',$this->path);
        if(empty($uri[0])) {
            $load->ctrl('home');
        }
        elseif(empty($uri[1])) {
            $load->ctrl($uri[0]);
        }
        else {
            $load->ctrl($uri[0],$uri[1]);
        }
    }
    else {
        $load->ctrl('index');
    }

    \* --- loader class --- *\
    public function ctrl($ctrl,$action=null) {
        $ctrl_name = 'Ctrl_'.ucfirst(strtolower($ctrl));
        $ctrl_path = ABS_PATH . 'ctrl/' . strtolower($ctrl) . '.php';
        if(file_exists($ctrl_path)) { require_once $ctrl_path;}

        $ctrl = new $ctrl_name();

        is_null($action) ? $action = "__default" : $action = strtolower($action);
        $ctrl->$action();
    }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Which MVC framework are you using?

Comment: @Jonathan, as mentioned in the question, im using a custom framework (learning for the sake of learning)...i can therefore choose whatever i'd like.i know there must be a simple way of getting around this problem, im just missing it... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle this within your controller. Typically, MVC frameworks will call a default method when the requested method isn't available. Simply overwrite this fallback-method to call your desired method and pass the parameter list in as parameters.

For instance, KohanaPHP has the `__call($method, $params)` method that is called when the requested method doesn't exist. You could handle the logic within this, or its functional equivalent in your MVC framework..

This would let you keep the logic internal to the controller itself rather than having it blasted out between various files.

Comment: i THINK i get what oyu mean...do you mean, if i have a index() method in my controller that gets called upon no supplied method, or no method found - bank on having that method called because the params won't match it, and then chop the URI apart in that method?

Comment: What I mean is you should have a missingMethod() method that gets called when a non-existent method is requested. In Kohana, the requested method is passed in as the first parameter, and the provided parameters follow. Just patch these through to your index() method, and you should be all set.

Comment: you edited right before i submitted my comment...and you answered my question, i think...hrm, im iffy on it, but im so taken back by diving into this framework, that its not hard to do right now:) its probably a great idea haha

Comment: I'm thinking about the structure. This method would allow you to keep your controller-logic within your controller :)